# How do I deal with Cross Origin issues when developing Cordova/Ionic Hybrid Apps

Tags: android, angularjs, web-services, cordova, drupal-7

I see some questions similar to my issue but they seem to not have answers.  I am developing a mobile app (or apps) using the ionic framework which uses Cordova/Phonegap.  So, it is a hybrid app because it will run inside the browser on the device, e.g. Android device.

I have a Drupal site which has a module called Services which exposes an API for the data on the Drupal site.  On the client side, I am trying to call that API and get back data.  I can get data back from the Drupal api using the Chrome REST Client.  However, when I run the command "ionic serve" which runs a server on localhost at a certain port, I get an error related to cross-browser issues.  Oh, I am using AngularJS on the front end, which ionic seems to prefer.  Ionic uses Cordova.  The app will get packaged as a Java app but ionic/cordova run in an embedded browser with HTML/JS/CSS.

The NG Book on Angular discusses CORS handling.  Do I have to configure Drupal also to accept cross origin requests?  There is a CORS module.  In this case, I have access to both the client and server.  Using the Services module of Drupal I configured an api.  However, that alone does not seem to be enough.  That module does not have any settings that deal with CORS.

Is it possible to handle this completely with client side code, specifically the Angular $http service or the $get service?
Or there is a separate Drupal CORS module.  Configuring that module is a bit confusing to me.  The documentation reads

"A list of paths and corresponding domains to enable for CORS. Multiple entries should be separated by a comma. Enter one value per line separated by a pipe, in this order:"

Internal path

Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Use to echo back the Origin header.

Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Examples:

*|http://example.com

api|http://example.com:8080 http://example.com

api/*|,https://example.com

api/*||POST|Content-Type,Authorization|true

None of the above examples include the words "Access-Control-Allow-" which kinda confuses me.  Maybe all I need is
api/*|http://example.com

Any advice would be helpful.
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: I am unaware of Drupal, but one thing I can assure you that configuration needs to be done from server side only.